# correct way to select row with date/time type

Tags: mysql

I have this `steps` table.

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| industry_id   | varchar(2)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| offset        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| create_date   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| flg           | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

these are sample data(I will just add few);

```
+--------+-------------+--------+---------------------+------+
| id     | industry_id | offset | create_date         | flg  |
+--------+-------------+--------+---------------------+------+
| 108587 | 12          |      1 | 2017-09-28 05:43:58 | 1    |
| 108588 | 12          |     51 | 2017-09-28 05:43:58 | 0    |
| 108589 | 12          |    101 | 2017-09-28 05:43:58 | 1    |
| 108590 | 12          |    151 | 2017-09-28 05:43:58 | 0    |
+--------+-------------+--------+---------------------+------+
```

I want to select data via create_date that are added 30 minutes ago and has flg=0. I tried different queries but failed.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM steps 
 WHERE flg=0 
   and create_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) AND NOW();
```

I tried this query but returns empty.

What could be the correct query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want

```
  create_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
```

to retrieve records newer than half an hour ago. You don't need `DATE_SUB()` when using `INTERVAL` style date arithmetic.

But, you may have timezone confusion.  Try this query:

```
 SELECT NOW(), steps.create_date, steps.*
   FROM steps
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 20
```

This will show the 20 most recent rows next to the current datestamp.  See if the value of `NOW()` is comparable to what you see in your `create_date` column. If not, explore the datatype of that column, and the time zone settings of the client connection inserting the rows vs. the client connection running this query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM steps 
WHERE flg = 0 AND create_date = NOW() - interval 30 minute
;
```

Using `=` will check whole date and minutes and seconds,

if you need some range - you have to use `between`:

```
create_date BETWEEN NOW() - interval 31 minute AND NOW() < interval 30 minute
```

Answer (score -1):

try using this

```
created_date >= DATE_ADD((now(), INTERVAL -15 MINUTE)) AND created_date < now()
```

links are below

[adddate() msql](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiFp5i-0MfWAhUKNY8KHaYvDokQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3resource.com%2Fmysql%2Fdate-and-time-functions%2Fmysql-adddate-function.php&usg=AFQjCNGWFLI2gh2BgVO3PxdsTxFacqjhKQ)

[now() mysql](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiwlYvo0MfWAhXJOo8KHeO3DYkQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fsql%2Ffunc_mysql_now.asp&usg=AFQjCNGiheE__wu9UWiN19e9LGWMkkngsA)

Comment: don't be use more links in answer